# Two Forms on one page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that submits an email address into my db and it works fine except if I wanna put more then one of them on a page. When I do that then it forces me to put the info in on what ever form is hirer up in the html. The code I have is the following:

```
$('#signup').submit(function() {
    $('#response').html('Adding email address...');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($('#email').val()),
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#signupResponse').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="signup" class="clear" action="" method="get">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Get the latest Poster Facts!</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Hit Me" class="signupButton" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="signupEmail" alt="Enter Email Address" />
</form>  
<span id="signupResponse"></span>
```

Now for me the easiest way I can think of fixing this would be to put the same exact code but change #signup and #signupResponse to something else but I figure there has got to be a better way.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing #signup and #signupResponse would work, and if you only have two forms, you could certainly do that.

If you want to make a generic version, you could do that with classes.  Change #signup to .ajaxForm (or something like that). Depending upon where #signupresponse is, you can do something like .parent() or .children('.response') to refer to it.  You can also use $(this) within the function to refer to the form that was selected, not all forms.

So for example, if your structure is

```
<div class="ajax-form">
    <form>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <span class="response"></span>
    <span class="signup-response"></span>
</div>
```

You could do :

```
$('.ajax-form form').submit(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.response').html('Adding email address...');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'send.php',
        data: 'ajax=true&email=' + escape($(this).children('.email').val()),
        success: function(msg) {
            $(this).parent().children('.signup-response').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

This generic format gives you one javascript for two forms.